# Do loop to assign bucket

Tags: sas

I have about 2330000 observations, I want to assign evenly spaced 10,000 buckets. The bucket criteria would the max(var)-min(var)/10,000. So for example, my maximum value is 3000 and my minimum value is -200, So my bucket size will be (3000+200)/10,000=0.32. So any value between -200 to (-200+0.32) should go to bucket 1, and any value between  (-200+0.32) to (-200+0.32*2) should go to bucket 2 and so on. The dataset will be something like this:

```
Var_value           bucket
-200                    1
-53                     ?
-5                      ?
-46                     ?
5
8
4
56
7542
242
....
```

How should the code be written? I am thinking a do loop but not sure how to do it? Can anyone help?

Comment: And what have you tried? Show some effort, this is not a free coding site.
Loops in almost every language are all over the net. [Look at this post of how to ask questions here](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow), I dont want to discourage you or be rude, but these are the rules, you should follow them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you would do with the proposed loop but this is what I'd do:

```
/* get some data to play with */
data a(keep=val);
do i=1 to 1000000;
    val = 3200*ranuni(0)-200;
    output;
end;
run;
/* groups=xxx specifies the number of buckets
   var yyy is the name of the variable whose values we'd like to classify
   ranks zzz specifies the name of the variable containing the assigned rank
*/
proc rank data=a out=b groups=10000;
var val;
ranks bucket;
run;
```

Comment: I don't know if this would necessarily give you exactly 10000 buckets because it works on a percentile basis and if you have a lot of ties there may not be distinct boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another approach you could use:

**Generate random simulated data**

```
data have;
    do i=1 to 250000;
        /*Seed is `_N_` so we'll see the same random item count.*/
        var_value = (ranuni(_N_)-0.5)*8000;
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

**Solution(s)**

```
/*Desired number of buckets.*/
    %let num_buckets = 10000;

/*Determine bucket size and minimum var_value*/
    proc sql noprint;
        select (max(var_value)-min(var_value))/&num_buckets.,
                min(var_value) 
        into : bucket_size,
             : min_var_value
        from have;
    quit;
    %put bucketsize: &bucket_size.;
    %put min var_value: &min_var_value.;

/*    1 - Assign buckets using data step */
    data want;
        set have;
        bucket = max(ceil((var_value-&min_var_value.)/&bucket_size.),1);
    run;
    proc sort data=want;
        by bucket;
    run;

/* or 2 - Assign buckets using proc sql*/
    proc sql;
        create table want as
        select var_value,
               max(ceil((var_value-&min_var_value.)/&bucket_size.),1) as bucket
        from have
        order by CALCULATED bucket;
    quit;
```